# Exchange Autoreply for Ex-Employee

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office-365, auto-reply

I've recently run into a problem where an employee had to leave quite suddenly and didn't have time to reassign or even note all of the cases they were working on, as a result I've decided the best course of action would be to enable an autoreply whenever anyone contacts him through his company email.

The issue i'm coming accross is that his Active Directory account has been disabled for security reasons, this means I can't use my normal method of assigning a generic admin account access to his mailbox and configuring it through there, it also means I can't use an exchange rule, or by extension an office365 rule.

I need about 275 Charachters minimum because I need to list 3 seperate mail addresses, so a tooltip alone is out of the question sadly.

My current way of thinking is to just assign his email address to a temporary account or recreate his account with alternate credentials, but this is certainly not best practice.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use a mail flow rule in Office 365?  It should not matter that the AD user is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the mailbox can still be accessed via PowerShell, you can run Get/Set-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration.  This will not cover a use case of a sender sending the departed user more than one email per day. You can set a different message for internal vs. external senders, as well as disabling external senders from getting an OOO message.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638217(v=exchg.150).aspx

My suggestion is to draft the message as you like in MS Word, save as HTML, and import the HTML file into a variable in PowerShell.  `$extmsg = get-content C:\filepath\file.html`  Then you can call in the $extmsg variable when assigning the AutoReply content in your Exchange cmdlet.  Word makes very "bulky" HTML files, but you can easily ensure `mailto` and `url` links work properly.

Disabling an AD account should not destroy the mailbox, but removing an assigned license subscription can.  Depending on your tenant plan, you should put the user on hold before deprovisioning the account from O365.  This will keep the mailbox data for the duration of the hold.